# Debugging: Right View of Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

Given a Binary Tree, find the Right view of it. The right view of a Binary Tree is a set of nodes visible when the tree is viewed from the right side.

Right view of the following tree:

> 1 3 7 8

```
          1
       /     \
     2        3
   /   \     / \
  4     5   6   7
    \
     8
```

**Example 1:**

*Input:*

```
       1
     /   \
    3     2
```

Output:

> 1 2

**Example 2:**

*Input:*

```
     10
    /  \
  20    30
 /   \
40  60
```

*Output:*

> 10 30 60

**Task:**
Just complete the function rightView() that takes node as parameter and returns the right view as a list.

**My Code:**

```
'''
# Node Class:
class Node:
    def init(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
'''
def func(list1,root,level,max_level):
    if not root:
        return
    if max_level<level:
        list1.append(root.data)
        max_level=level
    func(list1,root.right,level+1,max_level)
    func(list1,root.left,level+1,max_level)
def rightView(root):
   max_level = 0
   list1 = []
   func(list1,root,1,max_level)
   return list1
```

Note that when I submit this code I'm getting the Wrong Answer.

If I change `max_level = 0` to `max_level=[0]` and
all the other max_level lines like `max_level<level` to `max_level[0]<level` and `max_level=level` to `max_level[0]=level`.

If I make these changes, I'm getting the correct answer.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **max_level = 0**, this variable is not passed in the function by reference, So it is not updated for every function call using it.

```
func(list1,root.right,level+1,max_level)
func(list1,root.left,level+1,max_level)
```

Suppose you update the max_level in the first function call, although it remains the same as it is previously set for the second function call

While **max_level = [0]**, this list is ***passed by reference***, So when you make updates to it. Those changes are effective for all the function call using it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why it is not updating. I'm changing  ```max_level``` to ```level``` and also passing it as a function arguement.

Comment: @ArnavLuhadiya By passing references means using pointers. Still, you have confusion?

Comment: I may be very wrong but is this happening because integers,strings are immutable and lists are mutable?

Comment: @ArnavLuhadiya No, lists and strings are passed as the references(pointers) while primitive data types like integers are not.

Comment: @ArnavLuhadiya I think you should solve more problems based on recursion you will get to learn about the differences between various data types.

Comment: @ArnavLuhadiya If you have understood my answer, Could you accept/upvote my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are looking at the tree from the right, you will see only the last node of each level. What we have to is just to a level-order traversal and find the last node and append it to the result list.

To solve this initialize two lists: one for results, one for nodes of each level.

I defined `queue` list to store the nodes of each level. If you have 3 nodes in a level, that means you will be pushing 3 nodes from that level. That also means you will be checking if each node has left or right node for 3 times, because you have only 3 nodes. So you will be counting down 3 times, in the second while loop, when you finished checking all 3 items of this level, the last one you called will be stored as `currentNode` and after second while loop you will be pushing the last node to the list of results.

```
def rightSideView(root):
    if not root:
        return []
    result=[]
    queue=[root]
    while len(queue):
        count=0
        length=len(queue)
        while count<length:
            current_node=queue.pop(0)
            if current_node.left:
                queue.append(current_node.left)
            if current_node.right:
                queue.append(current_node.right)
            count+=1
        result.append(currentNode)
    return result
```